# How to install MPM worker on CentOS 5.3?

Tags: centos, mpm-worker

I use this command: yum install apache2-mpm-worker

with no success. Searching on google also not found

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the httpd.worker line in /etc/sysconfig/httpd:

```
# The default processing model (MPM) is the process-based
# 'prefork' model.  A thread-based model, 'worker', is also
# available, but does not work with some modules (such as PHP).
# The service must be stopped before changing this variable.
#
#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've done that and restarted apache.  I do an httpd -l and it only shows the prefork.c not the  worker.c .  I have checked the sbin directory and know for a fact the httpd.worker file exists.  ANy other ideas?

Comment: That's because httpd is the prefork compiled version and httpd.worker is the worker compiled version (two separate binaries).
The init script uses /usr/sbin/httpd unless it finds an alternative binary defined as the variable HTTPD in /etc/sysconfig/httpd, in which case it spawns that one instead.